GET request JSON body params in rswag specs
Issue
How can I write a rswag spec that would pass my_field: 'my_value' into my controller's params for a GET request?
Initial attempt
config/routes.rb:
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    resources :my_tests
  end
end

app/controllers/api/my_tests_controller.rb:
class Api::MyTestsController < Api::BaseController
  def index
    render json: do_something_with(params) # expect `params[:my_field] == 'my_value'`
  end
end

spec/api/my_tests/index_spec.rb:
RSpec.describe 'Test', type: :request do
  context 'on openapi spec' do
    let(:Authorization) { bearer_token }

    path '/api/my_tests' do
      get 'Test' do
        consumes 'application/json'
        produces 'application/json'
        security [bearerAuth: {}]
        parameter name: :my_field, in: :body, type: :string

        response '200', 'Test' do
          let(:my_field) { 'my_value' }

          run_test!
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

Produces invalid params:
{
  "\"my_value\"": nil,
  controller: "api/my_tests",
  action: "index",
  my_test: {}
}

Attempt trying to apply the solution that works for POST
Solutions found in https://github.com/rswag/rswag/issues/290 work for POST but not for GET.
spec/api/my_tests/index_spec.rb:
RSpec.describe 'Test', type: :request do
  context 'on openapi spec' do
    let(:Authorization) { bearer_token }

    path '/api/my_tests' do
      get 'Test' do
        consumes 'application/json'
        produces 'application/json'
        security [bearerAuth: {}]
        parameter name: :body, in: :body, schema: {
          type: :object,
          properties: {
            my_field: { type: :string },
          },
        }

        response '200', 'Test' do
          let(:body) { { my_field: 'my_value' } }

          run_test!
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

Produces invalid params:
{
  "{\"my_field\":\"my_value\"}": nil,
  controller: "api/my_tests",
  action: "index",
  my_test: {}
}

If the request is POST instead of GET, it produces valid params:
{
  "my_field": "my_value", # <- This is the field I want
  "controller": "api/my_tests",
  "action": "foo",
  "my_test": {
    "my_field": "my_value"
  }
}


I've just posted a bug report in rswag's repo: https://github.com/rswag/rswag/issues/786
Also, this issue is present for PATCH requests as well

were you able to resolve the issue in any way?

Unfortunately rswag doesn't support such GET requests using body
You can define such helper to patch the request:
def send_request(metadata)
  request = Rswag::Specs::RequestFactory.new.build_request(metadata, self)

  if request[:verb] == :get &&
      request[:payload].present? &&
      request[:headers]['CONTENT_TYPE'] == 'application/json'
    request[:payload] = JSON.parse(request[:payload])
  end

  send(
    request[:verb],
    request[:path],
    params: request[:payload],
    headers: request[:headers]
  )
end

And use it such way
it 'returns 200' do |example|
  send_request(example.metadata)

  expect(JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)).to eq(a: 1)
end


GET request params are based on the query (the trailing part of the URL following the ?).
The rswag DSL provides for passing params as part of the query string via in: :query, so this would look like:
parameter name: :my_field, in: :query, type: :string

